# Compare two HTML pages present behind firewall

Tags: comparison

I have two HTML pages, where the contents of the pages are column 1 and column2. Column1 has the same data in two pages, while column 2 is different( think column 2 as counter value). How do I compare these two pages

Options I have:

1) Use a tool I use(SoapUI may be) to write scripts and parse each html page
2) Use some built in library available for Java/Perl/Python

I'm looking for way like [quickdiff.com](http://quickdiff.com).

Note: The html pages are firewalled and are not accessible to public meaning diff tools available on internet don't work. The two html pages are instances from same website.

Any pointers on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

**Edit** : As I mentioned , html pages contains two columns where column 1 is same in both the pages and column2 is a counter value.. If column1 is having value "a" and column2 is 1 in page 1 then column1 is also "a" and column2 is 2 in page 2, these will be considered as different by diff command. I want to consider them as same. In other words ignore column2 and only see difference in column1

Comment: Can u please add in more description, not sure if i followed? May be as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `wget` and `diff` to show differences:

```
diff <(wget -q -O - http://www.site1.com/) <(wget -q -O - http://www.site2.com/)
```

Comment: The problem is webpages are in form of server names, would wget still work for some URI's like this <http://server1> <http://server2> ? I think i will try ur suggestion

Comment: Yes, it [supports](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format) any [valid URL](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

Comment: Beau - As I mentioned , html pages contains two columns where column 1 is same in both the pages and column2 is a counter.. If column1 is having value "a" and column2 is 1 in page 1 then column1 is also "a" and column2 is 2 in page 2, these will be considered as different by diff command. I want to consider them as same. In other words ignore column2 and only see difference in column1, does this make sense?